# openSSL mac undefined symbol

Tags: c, macos, openssl

I'm developing a TLSclient for MAC, and I'm having a little building my project on MACOSX (working very well on linux) and most particulary in using openssl libs.

Here's my console error I hope you could help me deal with:

```
gcc   -lpthread  -o *.o /opt//local/var/macports/software/openssl97/0.9.7m_0/opt/local/lib/openssl97/lib/libssl.a /opt//local/var/macports/software/openssl97/0.9.7m_0/opt/local/lib/openssl97/lib/libcrypto.a  -ldl 
Undefined symbols:
  "_SSL_CTX_set_info_callback", referenced from:
      _MTLSServer_Setup in MTLSServer.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [mtls_server] Error 1
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

In OpenSSL 0.9.7 `SSL_CTX_set_info_callback` is a macro, and your code is trying to link to a function. This probably means you don't have the correct path to the headers.

I'm a little puzzled for other things in your command line:

- Why are you statically linking with an old version of OpenSSL 0.9.7. Recent versions of Mac OS X have 0.9.8 included.
- The `-o *.o` seems to be an error it should be `-o something *.o`
- The `-lpthread` argument should be after libcrypto.

Comment: He's using GCC to invoke `ld` on the object files to link them. He's not compiling them with that command.

Comment: `/opt//local/var/macports/software/openssl97/0.9.7m_0/opt/local/lib/openssl97/lib/libssl.a` looks really odd. Are you certain of those paths? The result of `find /opt/local/ -iname libssl.a` for me is `/opt/local//lib/libssl.a`.